# AngularJS UI Router is there a way to know when the final state has been entered?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular1.6

I'm wondering if there is a way to know when the final child state has been entered for UI-Router.

Basically, here's some code...

```
$transitions.onFinish({ to : '*' }, (transition) => {
    ... do something
});
```

I'm doing something in there, but I only really want to do that something when the LAST CHILD STATE has been entered.

So basically, if I have states like:
`master -> layout -> child layout`
It can fire that `onFinish` two/three times, it goes top down...  This causes a little bit of a problem inside there.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Edit - 
This is something that I want happening for all child states.  It's a dynamic action.  The asterisk wildcard in the state transition is on purpose, and necessary.

Comment: Yes, @tanmay I can.  That's not the point.  The `do something` in there is something that I want to end up happening for *all child states*.  And it's something *dynamic*.  Like. . . Say. . . Setting meta tags based on state content. . .